# JavaScript | Detecting the WebKit over Browser/Phone Type

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to detect the web-kit engine (ie iPhone, Android, BlackBerry6) rather than detecting each phone or browser individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Webkit browsers should report the version of Webkit they are using, in their User agent string.

These are the user agent strings used by Safari, and Google Chrome on Mac OS X; similar strings are used by the browsers on other devices.

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.1 Safari/533.17.8
>   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.125 Safari/533.4